# wiring a 3 way dimmer switch into a multiway circuit located at 3 locations

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to put a 3 way dimmer switch into multiway light circuit to control the dimness of 3 light fixtures in that circuit.  I connected the dimmer up properly but the lights just barely dimmed.  I don't know if I had the proper dimmer for the situation, but I did notice that a white wire was used on the load side 3 way switch instead of the red wire.  Could that be my problem?  Can someone give me some direction and information about the proper dimmer to use?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you include a clear picture of the inside(s) of the boxes, showing all the wires and how they're connected?

Comment: What type dimmer did you use to have full control and dimming capability at multiple locations an electronic dimmer like a lutron maestro type switch will be needed, I am not connected to lutron but like this product and have installed quite a few in my homes and installed quite a few for others. (Easy diy though).

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved pleased?